# Scala compilation error in IntelliJ: could not find an output directory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, dotty

IntelliJ IDEA (most recent community version) fails to compile the dotty compiler with the error:

```
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Could not find an output directory for
/src/contrib/dotty/scala-backend/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/ScalaPrimitivesOps.scala
in List(
(/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/test-resources,/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/classes),
(/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/resource_managed/main,/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/classes),
(/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main,/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/classes),
(/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/test,/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/classes),
(/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/src,/src/contrib/dotty/compiler/target/scala-2.12/classes))
```

Clearly there is nothing wrong with the code, and Dotty seems to compile fine using sbt, because the `run` command works. **Is there something special that needs to be done for an sbt project to make IDEA compile using sbt?** Is that causing this error? Otherwise, what does this error mean?

**To Reproduce**

1. Use new install of IntelliJ IDEA after deleting any settings from previous installations.
2. Download the repository with `git clone --recursive https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty`
3. Make sure newest version of `sbt` is installed. Run `sbt managedSources` from the root directory of the project.
4. Import into IntelliJ using the setting `Import project from external model` of type `sbt` with the Oracle JDK 1.8. Otherwise keep defaults.
5. Right click on the project in the project explorer and choose `Load/Unload Modules...`. Unload all modules except `dotty`, `dotty-compiler`, `dotty-library` and `dotty-interfaces`. (The modules listed in http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/contributing/intellij-idea.html)
6. In the project explorer, click on `compiler`. From the `Build` menu click `Build Module 'dotty-compiler'`.

**What does not fix it**

It does not fix anything to do `File` => `Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

It does not fix anything to keep all modules loaded.

Comment: `ScalaPrimitivesOps.scala` from your error message belongs to an unloaded module. It shouldn't be picked up by a compiler at all, and I couldn't reproduce this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use a built-in sbt shell for compiling sbt projects:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but my question was not a very good one. Using the IntelliJ build command is not the recommended way. The dotty getting started guide uses a separate shell and remote debugging: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/contributing/intellij-idea.html

Answer (score 1):

From my experience one reason for this kind of errors is if you have opened the output folder in shell or something like this. It looks like sometimes IDEA tries to delete the whole folder and if it can't do that because the folder is used, it mysteriously results in such a error.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. In my case, this was not the problem.